# How to centralise routing in Flask using a single file instead of decorators?

Tags: python, routes, flask

I would like to know, if possible, how to have a single file (ex: `routes.py`) which maps the routes with procedures spread accross different python files/modules.

How can I do this?

I am pretty new to Flask and this. I tried to search but I suppose do to lack of using correct terms, I couldn't find a solution.

I am sure there must be a way.

Thank you.

Comment: For what it is worth, I wrote an extension called [`Flask-HipPocket`](https://github.com/svieira/Flask-HipPocket) that makes centralized, lazy-loaded URL mapping as easy as `mapper = Mapper(app, "base.import.path"); mapper.add("/", "some.callable")` </shameless-plug>

Comment: Thank you @SeanVieira, I will make sure to check it out, even if it's just to try to learn from the codebase. Thanks! PS. If you have the time, would you care to give a simple, real-lifeish example as to why or when you might want to make use of "lazy loading"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know decorators work as functions:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'home'
```

equivalent to:

```
def home():
    return 'home'

home = app.route('/')(home)
```

But `Flask` already has special method `add_url_rule` for this. It used in `route` decorator.

```
def home():
    return 'home'

app.add_url_rule('/', None, home, {})
```

So you can create special module where will import view functions and add routes with `add_url_rule`. Do not forget execute this code before usage (import).

`add_url_rule` is creating `Rule` instance and adding it to `Flask.url_map`, so you can also explicitly create `Rule` and put it to `url_map`. But I hope this not need for you.

**Update**

With `Flask` you also can use `Lazily Loading Views`, see details in documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/lazyloading/.

Comment: Thank you very much @tbicr. Further explanations are very much appreciated as well!

Comment: +1 - also, it's worth pointing out that there is also a section [in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/lazyloading/) that talks about lazy loading. :-)